# bitnami redmine problem running post-install step

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I’m trying to install Bitnami Redmine on my computer but the following worning appears:
Problem running post-install step. installationmay not comrrectly 
Error running c:\ noysarah/apps/redmine\scripts\redmineini.bet : rake aborted!
HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point a directory

If I’m pressing the ‘X’ button the downloads continues. But then when the browser open I’m getting the following message:
“The requested URL was not found on this server”

If someone can help it will be amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

Could you please run the following command in a prompt?

```
set HOME
```

If you don't have set HOMEDRIVE or HOMEPATH, you have to set them before running the installer. For example, you could set them like this (if your user is `Administrator`):

```
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Administrator
```

I hope it helps.